# Insert new lines with missing values in a array

Tags: shell, awk

I have a data like below:

```
2016-07-25:06   5
2016-07-25:07   1
2016-07-25:08   1
2016-07-25:09   2
2016-07-25:10   1
2016-07-25:11   1
2016-07-25:13   9
2016-07-25:14   1
```

In the above i should display hours from 00 to till 23, like below:

```
2016-07-25:00   0
2016-07-25:01   0
2016-07-25:02   0
2016-07-25:03   0
2016-07-25:04   0
2016-07-25:05   0
2016-07-25:06   5
2016-07-25:07   1
2016-07-25:08   1
2016-07-25:09   2
2016-07-25:10   1
2016-07-25:11   1
2016-07-25:12   0
2016-07-25:13   9
2016-07-25:14   1
2016-07-25:15   0
2016-07-25:16   0
2016-07-25:17   0
2016-07-25:18   0
2016-07-25:19   0
2016-07-25:20   0
2016-07-25:21   0
2016-07-25:22   0
2016-07-25:23   0
```

could you please let  me know how can i achieve this using awk?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using awk you can do this:

```
awk -F '[:[:blank:]]+' '{for (;i<$2; i++) printf "%s:%02d\t0\n", $1, i; print; i++; s=$1}
        END{for (;i<24; i++) printf "%s:%02d\t0\n", s, i}' file

2016-07-25:00   0
2016-07-25:01   0
2016-07-25:02   0
2016-07-25:03   0
2016-07-25:04   0
2016-07-25:05   0
2016-07-25:06   5
2016-07-25:07   1
2016-07-25:08   1
2016-07-25:09   2
2016-07-25:10   1
2016-07-25:11   1
2016-07-25:12   0
2016-07-25:13   9
2016-07-25:14   1
2016-07-25:15   0
2016-07-25:16   0
2016-07-25:17   0
2016-07-25:18   0
2016-07-25:19   0
2016-07-25:20   0
2016-07-25:21   0
2016-07-25:22   0
2016-07-25:23   0
```

Comment: Thank you So much anubhava for your help, this work for me. Also could you please explain me in detailed what the above command is doing, that would really appreciate. especially what do you meant by [:[:blank:]]+ Thank you!!

Comment: `[:blank:]' matches a space or tab. `[:[:blank:]]+` is character class that matches 1 or more of colon or space or tab for splitting the fields. We are doing so that we can hour number in `$2`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[:[:space:]]+" }

function prt() {
    if ( NR > 1 ) {
        for (i=0; i<=23; i++) {
            printf "%s:%02d%s%d\n", $1, i, OFS, val[$1,i]
        }
        delete val
    }
}

$1 != prev { prt() }
{ val[$1,$2+0]=$3; prev=$1 }
END { prt() }
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
2016-07-25:00 0
2016-07-25:01 0
2016-07-25:02 0
2016-07-25:03 0
2016-07-25:04 0
2016-07-25:05 0
2016-07-25:06 5
2016-07-25:07 1
2016-07-25:08 1
2016-07-25:09 2
2016-07-25:10 1
2016-07-25:11 1
2016-07-25:12 0
2016-07-25:13 9
2016-07-25:14 1
2016-07-25:15 0
2016-07-25:16 0
2016-07-25:17 0
2016-07-25:18 0
2016-07-25:19 0
2016-07-25:20 0
2016-07-25:21 0
2016-07-25:22 0
2016-07-25:23 0
```

Answer (score 0):

This uses more tools than just awk, but it might be helpful:

```
#!/bin/bash
date="2016-07-25" #or a method to get the date you are interested in

#Generate all the zero lines
remaining=`for i in 0{0..9} {10..23}; do echo "$date:$i   0"; done | grep -v "$(cat datafile | awk '{print $1}')"`

#Add the original data and sort the lines
echo -e "$remaining\n$(cat datafile)" | sort -n
```

Comment: You can also use process substitution.  I would have written the `grep` like `grep -vf <(cut -d" " -f1 datafile)`, and the sort like `sort -n <(echo -e "${remaining}") datafile`.
You have another solution without `grep` with `uniq` looking at the first characters:
`sort -r <( for i in 0{0..9} {10..23}; do echo "$date:$i   0"; done ) datafile | uniq -w 15 | sort`

Comment: You can make the for-loop easier with `for i in {0..23}; do printf "%s:%02d   0\n" $date $i; done`, the `%02d` will add a zero when needed.

Comment: google UUOC, google deprecated backticks, and read [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) to understand some, but not all, of the reasons not to do this.